# BigQuery: Multiple queries SQL queries in the same statement

Tags: google-bigquery

I am investigating the relationship between power and speed of a device at different temperatures. I can easily create the SQL to this for one temperature range eg 2C to 5C, now I'm looking to see how I might run the same query just with different temperature range inside the one query. I am wanting to be able to run the code from within Google Sheets via the dataconnector (that bit works fine) and then use the charting

I looked at various Unions but the ones I found here don't suit my use case

```
SELECT
Power,
AVG (Speed) AS Speed_freezing_2
FROM `gcp_project.dataset.table`
WHERE Power > 49 AND Power < 950 AND Temperature <= 2
GROUP BY Power ORDER BY Power
```

No idea if images will work here, but here's what I'd like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjSje.jpg

Comment: I've been offline for a few days travelling. I've now accepted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH ranges AS (
  SELECT 0 start, 2 finish UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 20, 50
)
SELECT start, finish, Power, AVG (Speed) avg_speed
FROM ranges, `project.dataset.table`
WHERE Power > 49 AND Power < 950
AND Temperature > start AND Temperature <= finish
GROUP BY start, finish, Power
ORDER BY Power, start
```

Comment: I found this to be the best approach for me - thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention that after I created the Sheets / BigQuery connections and command, I did a pivot which then put the temperature into columns, and I use the speed as value

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple averages in the same query and include the filter in a CASE inside each AVG. Something like this:

```
SELECT
Power,
AVG (case when Temperature<=2 then Speed end) AS Speed_freezing_2
AVG (case when Temperature>2  and Temperature<=5 then Speed end) AS Speed_cold_2_5
.......
FROM `gcp_project.dataset.table`
WHERE Power > 49 AND Power < 950
GROUP BY Power 
ORDER BY Power
```